# Sql Server 2016 Performance is terrible doing very simple inserts

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, performance

I am hoping someone can help me troubleshoot performance of sql server 2016.

Here are the 2 setups I have and I am comparing them

- Older dell lattitude laptop (i7 cpu, 16gb ram ssd)
      Windows 10
      Sql Server 2014 Developer edition (x64)
- Newer dell (xeon cpu, 32gb ram, a lot faster ssd - 3x faster than my older laptop ssd in my tests)
      Windows 10
      Sql Server 2016 Developer edition (x64)

Both versions of sql server were installed using all the default configuration. I really quickly noticed
performance difference between the two

- restoring small database from backup takes about 5x longer on sql server 2016 (same database)
- inserting 11K data rows into an empty table without indexes (database is not in use other than app inserting data)
      sql server 2014 - 2 seconds
      sql server 2016 - 32 seconds

I have so far looked at the following

- error log does not have any errors.
- sys.dm_exec_query_stats  does not give me any clues so far (it tells me that insert is slow, but since there are no scans, no
  indexes not sure what it can tell me)
- running sql server profiler does not show any problems
- doing some timers in code shows that the entire time is spent executed command object.

some details about the program

- dot.net 4.6.1 wpf app
- reads csv files and inserts data into a table
- the insert is done on a brackground thread using async
- timers clearly show that the problem is not with parsing csv file or anything else - just inserts
- SqlCommand object (as well as db connection) is being reused
- no explicit transactions specified
- when comparing 2 computers, the same exact program running doing the same exact thing (basically the only difference that I am looking at is hardware and different sql server version)

I am looking for some help to understand where to even start troubleshooting this. Here is what I am going to do next:
        install sql server 2016 on the older laptop and see if inserts are as fast as they were in sql server 2014 or will I see a significant slowdown

thanks

Comment: If you see the behavior even restoring small databases, I'd start looking at lower-level things like hardware, disks, bus throughput, low-level input handlers, anti-virus programs, etc. There's got to be an 800 lb gorilla around there somewhere. Is the box w/SS2016 also hosting anything like virtual machines?

Comment: just curious...  did ss2016 need to grow any of the database files for this operation? Could file initialization play a role? https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/

Comment: Unlikely as it is this could be related to your problem, it at least sounds like this could be worth a few seconds reading - if you see high CPU with these slow inserts,take a look at  sys.dm_os_spinlock_stats; a high "spins" value could be indicative of a threading problem addressed in Cumulative Update 2 as noted here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3195888/fix-high-cpu-usage-causes-performance-issues-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: You are comparing performance differences between versions but you are using the 2014 backup and restoring it to 2016. There are some maintenance tasks you need to complete when changing versions. Updating statistics and rebuilding indexes are some. Without first getting your 2016 up to a valid running configuration your comparisons are not going to accurately reflect anything.

Comment: thanks for the ideas.  

David W - I have come to the same conclusion. No, I am not hosting anything else on it (it's my local dev box)

SqlZim - no, the amount of data I insert is really small and the files never grow (I am inserting into a blank db every time)

Comment: David W - CPU is very low, but IO is 100%. I tested my SSD to see if that is a problem but so far all the tools show my SSD is lightning fast. I am running sql server version 13.0.4001.0, which I believe is the latest

Sean Lange - I am not really comparing using the restored database. The app I am working on is a wizard that creates a clean db using a script every time. Restoring a db is just something I have noticed because of how slow things were.

Comment: I have not changed sql server 2014 on older computer to sql server 2016 - I noticed that inserts run slower, but not that bad (sql server 2014 was 2 seconds for 11K inserts, 2016 is 4 seconds for 11K inserts).  My main laptop - I reinstalled sql server 2016 (as well as upgraded BIOS, installed various hardware updated drivers from Dell that I thought might help) - the result is the same. Inserting 11K records takes about 37 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Thank for all the help. After some time troubleshooting and looking around I found this post: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1107759/slow-ssd-performance-toshiba-1gb-nvme)
I ran AS SSD Benchmark and right away noticed a huge problem with my harddrive (I guess not all SSD Benchmark software is created equal - the other one I tried showed me that my SSD rocks). I will now be focused on how to address this problem. Thank you all